# Is there any way to find Rows that don't have a match? or Null?

Tags: c#, excel, linq, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I am currently creating an Attendance application but I am having a hard time matching a schedule where there is no logs to mark it as absent.

As of the moment this is how my table looks like

**Current Table**
[image: Current Table]

As of the moment, the table will only show which schedule has attendance logs on it. So I can't see if there is a schedule which the employee hasn't shown up which s/he is absent.

I have tried matching it with null, but it ends up not showing anything.

This is my code to populate the table

```
public void Main()
        {
            // works but not the midnight cross stuff
            var final = (from a1 in EmployeeAttendanceLogs
                         join a2 in EmployeeAttendanceLogs on a1.ID equals a2.ID
                         join t1 in EmployeeScheduleList on a1.ID equals t1.ID
                         join t2 in EmployeeScheduleList on a2.ID equals t2.ID
                         join d1 in EmployeeDetails on t1.ID equals d1.EmployeeID
                         where ((a1.LogStatus == 0 && t1.In == t2.In) && (((((a1.ActualLog - t1.In ).Ticks) > TimeSpan.FromHours(1).Ticks) || t1.In.Date == a1.ActualLog.Date) && t1.In.Date == a1.ActualLog.Date )) && (a2.LogStatus == 1 && t1.Out == t2.Out && (t2.Out.Date == a2.ActualLog.Date) )
                         select new
                         {
                             User_ID = t1.ID,
                             Name = d1.EmployeeName,
                             Scheduled_In = t1.In,
                             Actual_Login = a1.ActualLog,
                             Scheduled_Out = t2.Out,
                             Actual_Out = a2.ActualLog
                         }).Distinct(). ToList();

            tbContainer = StaticClasses.ToDataTable(final);

            dgvAttendance.ItemsSource = emp.CalculateEmployeeAttendance(tbContainer);
        }
```

And these are my sources of data

**Employee Schedule File**

[image: Employee Schedule]

**Employee Attendance Logs File**

[image: Attendance Logs]

As based from the logs Employee 5 has no record and this is the output to the grid

[image: Output]

So it doesn't show, but I have also tried to set my class to have a logic

**Employee Schedule Class**

```
public class EmployeeSchedule
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    { get
        {
            if (_name == null)
            {
                _name = "";
            }
            return _name;
        }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string scheduleeIn { get; set; }

    private string _actualIn;
    public string actualIn
    {
        get
        {
            if (_actualIn == null) 
            {
                _actualIn = "Absent";
            }
            return _actualIn;
        }
        set { _actualIn = value; }

    }

    public string scheduleOut { get; set; }

    public string _actualOut;
    public string actualOut
    {
        get
        {
            if (_actualOut == null)
            {
                _actualOut = "Absent";
            }
            return _actualOut;
        }
        set { _actualOut = value; }

    }

    private string _tardiness;
    public string tardiness
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tardiness == null) 
            {
                _tardiness = "Absent";
            }
            return _tardiness;
        }
        set { _tardiness = value; }
    }

    private string _workHours;
    public string workHours
    {
        get
        {
            if (_workHours == null) 
            {
                _workHours = "Absent";
            }
            return _workHours;
        }
        set { _workHours = value; }
    }    
}
```

It's been a day already I have tried figuring it out but it doesn't seem to show up or to mark the schedule as absent.

Any ideas or suggestion would be of great help. Thanks

Edit : Sources of Data

Here is the source of data for my Attendance Logs

**Attendance Logs**

```
public class Actual
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActualLog { get; set; }
        public int LogStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
```

**Employee Schedule**

```
public class Emp1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime In { get; set; }
    public DateTime Out { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: seems outer join is what you looking for

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi can you give me an example if you don't mind?

Comment: to help, could you start by showing us some SQL statement that works against the db, then we could help translate that to Linq

Comment: @JohnB I have forgotten to mention that I don't have a DB, I just have two files then put them on a list

Comment: @JohnB I just get my data from the two files, the excel and the .dat files. then put tit on a list. then compare them using linq

Comment: JohnB: you should not start with a SQL statement, you should start with proper table definitions and a proper requirement. Without those you don't know whether the SQL statement would return what you want.